# Django: How to hide Sites framework from Django Admin while using django-allauth?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-sites

## Background

I have a `django` server that uses `django-allauth` for handling authentication logic. I want to `unregister` Sites framework from `django-admin`, in other words, I do not want to see the Sites section inside django-admin:

[image: Django-admin current state]

## What I tried

Normally, I would do one of the two things:

1. Unplug `django.contrib.sites` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
2. Unregister `Sites` model from within one of my `admin.py` files like so: `admin.site.unregister(Sites)`

## The problem

I tried doing both options above. Here is the error when I unplug Sites app from `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```sh
...
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 78, in <module>
    class Site(models.Model):
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 113, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

`django-allauth` is clearly using it in line 13.

Here is the error when I do `admin.sites.unregister(Site)`:

```sh
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\accounts\admin.py", line 94, in <module>
    admin.site.unregister(Site)
  File "C:\path-to-my-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 153, in unregister
    raise NotRegistered('The model %s is not registered' % model.__name__)
django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model Site is not registered
```

The issue is `django-allauth` requires the Sites framework in order to work properly. Here is [the official explanation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> settings.py (Important - Please note ‘django.contrib.sites’ is required as INSTALLED_APPS):

## What I want

All I want is to hide the sites section from django-admin, as I have no use for it. I do not want to unplug or unregister, because I want `django-allauth`'s functionality intact.
How do I achieve this? What am I missing?

## Steps to reproduce the error

1. Create a Django project with `django-allauth` installed
2. Create a superuser and log into Django admin
3. Try to hide the sites framework from Django admin

Comment: Try to put `admin.site.unregister(Sites)` on one of your `AppConfig.ready()` functions

Comment: @BrianDestura It worked. But why did it work? You may post your full answer, I will accept it with pleasure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to unregister the `Site` admin on one of your `AppConfig.ready()` functions like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class SomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # ...

    def ready(self):
        from django.contrib import admin
        from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
        admin.site.unregister(Site)
```

The error happens because doing the unregister on one of your `admin.py` will not guarantee that the register for the `django.contrib.sites` has already finished. Doing this in a `ready()` function will work because all apps are already registered along with their admins.